# How to make xml declaration and stylesheet in single line

Tags: xml, stylesheet, declaration

Basically this part of my project i am unable to figure out how to make the xml declaration and the reference to the stylesheet into a single line?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<?xml-stylesheet href="sweetShop.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

Comment: If you're only using the XML declaration to specify version 1.0, you can omit it completely. See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-prolog-dtd.

Comment: Thanks alot! That's great to know!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet href="sweetShop.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

Well, that was easy...

Comment: I just thought there was a way to combine them but i suppose it was a silly question.. thanks